# 'full screen' looping background video for AIR based iOS application

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, video, starling-framework

I'm creating an AIR based app, targeting the iPad, where I want to use a 'full screen' looping video in the background.

In the foreground are moving and animated elements, anywhere from 5-50 total.

Does this sound like a project that would warrant the use of Starling?
Or should I opt for using the standard display list and simply target the GPU when I compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starling might struggle with video. Although there might be a workaround, the framework doesn't support video yet. I'm pretty sure the frame rate you would get for the video wouldn't be very high.

You might be able to run StageVideo under the native Flash Display List. I know you can't run Starling over StageVideo.

It should be a fairly quick job to set up a prototype with a looping video in the background and add 50 animated elements to test the performance.

If you're including iPad 1 in your targets you should do your testing on that device.